# Compojure Ring Middleware How To Use Value Outside of Middleware

Tags: clojure, middleware, compojure, ring

I have a simple route and middleware setup with compojure/swagger that is utilizing a ring middleware.

```
(POST "/worlds" [request]
      :body-params [name :- String]
      :header-params [token :- String]
      :middleware [wrap-api-auth]
      :summary "Creates a new world with 'name'"
      (ok (do-something-with-user)

(defn wrap-api-auth [handler]
  (fn [request]
    (let
      [token (get (:headers request) "token")
       user (db/get-user-by-token token)]
      (if user
        (handler request)     ; pass to wrapped handler
        (unauthorized {:error "unauthorized"})))))
```

This defines a simple route with some basic auth. The token passed in the header param is used to make a database query, which either returns a user and continues, or returns false and fails.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to pass the returned user back out so that I can use it later. I haven't had any luck, as I don't really know where I would try to add it to that I could access it later. I've tried to `assoc` it with the `request` but it doesn't appear that I can access it later. The ideal situation is I'm able to pass it to the `do-something-with-user` function.

Comment: _I've tried to assoc it with the request ..._ I've had success doing exactly that. Can you show how you tried to do that and how you tried to access it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `assoc` to add some data to the request should totally work.

You can find an example with some code that is very close to what I have in production at https://gist.github.com/ska2342/4567b02531ff611db6a1208ebd4316e6#file-gh-validation-clj-L124

In essence, that middleware calls

```
(handler (assoc request
                :validation {:valid true
                             :validation valid?}))
```

So for your case, the following should just work:

```
(handler (assoc request
                :user user))
```

If I understood correctly, the destructuring syntax you use is from [compojure-api](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api). According to the example at https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api/wiki/Middleware I'd say that the middleware set via the `:middleware` key behaves just as expected and you should be able to extract the `:user` from the `request` that ultimately ends up in your route.

So, just pass the `request` on to the `do-something-with-user` function:

```
(POST "/worlds" request
      :body-params [name :- String]
      :header-params [token :- String]
      :middleware [wrap-api-auth]
      :summary "Creates a new world with 'name'"
      (ok (do-something-with-user request))
```

It should contain the `:user` you `assoc`ed into it in your middleware function. Note the missing brackets around `request` like mentioned in the comments to this answer.

Comment: Thank you, this worked but I had to do (POST "/worlds" request.... outside of the []. Not sure why otherwise I'd get an error.

Comment: Ah, that's subtle and I didn't see it. Sorry. You can find the documentation for the destructuring at https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Destructuring-Syntax The compojure.api project re-implements that. See

Comment: https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api/blob/master/src/compojure/api/meta.clj#L604 (missing link from previous comment)

Comment: Updated the answer and removed the brackets.